# Visual Basic How to add a Destinct Combobox from a comma-delimited file instead of a database?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

delimited files what i need is to read from a comma-delimited file and retrieve ownley certain lines off them to a combobox, the combobox must then ownley show destinct names. I added a database-working code below of what im looking for but instaed of using a database i need the code for comma-delimeted files.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call combo1()
    End Sub
    Sub combo1()
        Dim com As SqlConnection
        com = New SqlConnection("Server = Q-DESIGN\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Q-Design Test Results; Trusted_Connection = true;")
        com.Open()
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Testname) from URL", com)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        End While
        reader.Close()
        com.Dispose()
        com.Close()
    End Sub
```

My comma delimited file will have the following lines for egsample

```
Jenny, 25, Female
Micheal, 100, Female
shaun, 50, male
Cindy, 75, Female
Cindy, 30, Female
Cindy, 20, Female
Micheal, 30, Female
deric, 50, Male
```

I need the combobox to show every name, ownley once

Comment: What's wrong in your code?

Comment: The code above works fine when using a database, what i need is an alternative code to get data from a comma delimited file instead of from a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) and a [`HastSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb359438.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

Here's a simple example:

```
' a set to store the names
Dim names = new HashSet(Of String)
Using reader = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\your\path")

    reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not reader.EndOfData
        Try
            ' read rows and add first field to set
            currentRow = reader.ReadFields()
            names.Add(currentRow(0).ToString())
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            ' do something
        End Try 
    End While 
End Using

' bind data to combo box (or use Items.Add instead)
comboBox.DataSource = names.ToList()
```

Comment: thankyou for the help, if i selected one of those items in the desinct combobox is there a way to then auto fill the next combobox with ownley the next rows destinc data for the selected items rows.

Comment: Ill put it in as a new question

Answer (score 0):

First I would read in the file one line at a time. I would then use regular expressions to extract the name field your looking for. Next I would add each item to a SortedSet.

```
Dim strLine as String = ""
Dim RX as New Regex("^([^,]*),")
Dim MyMatch as Match
Dim NameLookup as New SortedSet(Of String)

'
' Code to read in each line into strLine using StreamReader.
'

MyMatch = RX.Match(strLine)

If MyMatch.Success AndAlso Not NameLookUp.Contains(MyMatch.Result("${1}")) Then
   NameLookup.Add(MyMatch.Result("${1}"))
End If
```

After this adding the items from the SortedSet to the ComboBox should be fairly easy.

Also you can also manually create a DataTable with a "Name" column and use data bindings 
to automatically populate the combobox.