# Populate a second combobox with data from the first combobox and a comma-delimited file

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combobox that gets distinct data from a comma-delimited file.
I need to use that distinct data and populate a second combobox containing only information about the first combo box. 
Example:
Here's my comma-delimited files text.

```
Jenny, 25, Female
Micheal, 100, Female, hdfgh
shaun, 50, male
Cindy, 75, Female
Jenny, 25, Female
Micheal, 100, Female
shaun, 50, male
Cindy, 50, Female
Carry, 75, Female
```

And here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call combo1()
    Call combo2()
End Sub

Sub combo1()
    ' a set to store the names
    Dim names = New HashSet(Of String)
    Using reader = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\here.txt")

        reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not reader.EndOfData
            Try
                ' read rows and add first field to set
                currentRow = reader.ReadFields()
                names.Add(currentRow(0).ToString())
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                ' do something
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    ' bind data to combo box (or use Items.Add instead)
    ComboBox1.DataSource = names.ToList()
End Sub

Sub combo2()
    ' a set to store the names
    Dim names = New HashSet(Of String)
    Using reader = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\here.txt")

        reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not reader.EndOfData
            Try
                ' read rows and add first field to set
                currentRow = reader.ReadFields()
                names.Add(currentRow(1).ToString())
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                ' do something
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    ' bind data to combo box (or use Items.Add instead)
    ComboBox2.DataSource = names.ToList()
End Sub
```

This works fine to populate distinct data into each combobox, but I want the second combobox to only populate data from the selected item in combobox 1, example if I selected 
"Cindy" the next combobox must only show 25 and 75 not all the distinct resauls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Basic How to add a Destinct Combobox from a comma-delimited file instead of a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468627/visual-basic-how-to-add-a-destinct-combobox-from-a-comma-delimited-file-instead)

Comment: @KenWhite no, this question is different. it builds up on he question you mention. here nikki needs to bind a second combobox based on first's selected row.

Comment: I basically need to populate a second combobox but ownley with rows selected regarding the first combo boxes selected value so it might seem like a duplicate question but its not the same thing

Comment: the previos questions a type of "select all" and this question is "select all where"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind the first combobox the way you are doing. trap the combobox `SelectedValueChanged` event. 
use the`SelectedValue` property, do a second pass on the file. This time add values to the different hashset like this:

```
Dim ages = New HashSet(Of String)
    Using reader = New Microsoft.Visua...   ...FieldParser("C:\here.txt")

        reader.TextFieldType = Micros...   ....eldType.Delimited
        reader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not reader.EndOfData
            Try
                '   v--- THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT ---v
                if currentRow(0).ToString() = combobox1.selectedvalue then

                    ages.Add(currentRow(1).ToString())
                end if
```

you get the idea

```
    ' bind data to combo box (or use Items.Add instead)
    ComboBox2.DataSource = ages.ToList()
```

write acceptance code in `ComboBox2` `SelectedValueChanged`

Comment: thankyou for understanding my question, Your answer worked great thankyou what i did was the following as u said and it workd just fine at the top of the sub Dim ages = New HashSet(Of String) Dim names = New HashSet(Of String) and then currentRow = reader.ReadFields() names.Add(currentRow(0).ToString()) If currentRow(0).ToString() = ComboBox1.SelectedValue Then ages.Add(currentRow(1).ToString()) End If and at the bottom ComboBox2.DataSource = ages.ToList()